# jQuery curved corners problem troubleshooting in ie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, curvycorners

This will blow your mind...

Check out http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html using IE

Curved corners look nice on their examples, right?

Then visit http://veeter.com/wtf.php

I have copied http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html source code into that page exactly as it was displayed, except for a few technicalities. The only thing I changed was to add a base href to the header of the html so that could reference all of the relative URLs found in their test code.

And tell me what do you see?

Why are curved corners not working on my website?

Comment: We'll need more specifics - it's working in IE 8 for me...

Comment: Wild guess: could be a jQuery 1.5 incompatibility, that plugin is built for 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try Progressive Internet Explorer? It works just fine.
[http://css3pie.com](http://css3pie.com/)